# Can't update clob with foreign characters using UPDATEXML in Java

Tags: java, xml, oracle, clob

I am trying to update Georgian characters into a clob that is used for XML. I had to use clob, since the text is usually quite large. this is my update part:

```
select = "update datadocumentxml d\n" +
                "   set d.datadocumentxml = updatexml(xmltype(d.datadocumentxml),'/Comments/@Comment', ?)\n" + 
                "                                   .getClobVal(),\n" + 

                " where d.processengineguid = fnguidjava2raw(?)\n" + 
                "   and d.datadocumentid = 'Comments'";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);

    ps.setClob(1,clob);
    ps.setString(2,processid);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

this code works perfectly on English, Russian, Arabic and some characters. But when I try to update Georgian letters that are like 6+ characters, I get internal errors. I also tried Japanese letters and they don't work either.

this is the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, 
arguments: [17114], [0x7FEA96179698], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17114], [0x7FEA96179698], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor845.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:125)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy949.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at ge.bog.integration.crif.data.collector.connector.parallelcomments.UpdateXml.setComment(UpdateXml.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
... 46 more
```

I think it has something to do with JDBC drivers and charsets..

any suggestion would be greatly helpful. thanks.

Comment: For ORA-00600 internal errors, you might need to end up opening an Oracle Support ticket. But the alert log on the server should have more details about the cause of the error.